# Property declaration code being executed after page load in ASP.Net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following scenario.

I have a page class that has some properties.

Here is my class

```
public partial class p : System.Web.UI.Page
{
        private int? X
        {
            get
            {
                return // some helper method will return the value of X;
            }
        }
}   
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // in the page load event
   var d = X;
}
```

If I put a break point in the get of the property and in the var d = X line.

The page load event is executing before the get helper method calling ?

I am trying to understand why this is happening ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A getter/setter, in essence, is nothing different than a method call, just a shorthand syntax. Your code would logically be the same as

```
public partial class p : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private int? GetX()
    {
        return // some helper method will return the value of X;
    }
}   
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // in the page load event
   var d = GetX();
}
```

The getter will not save any value or do anything than return whatever the code specifies whenever it is called. Does that make sense to you?